# Which field can be used in django serializers for entering ipaddress with subnet mask

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

Which field can be used in django serializers for entering ipaddress with subnet mask. example: `x.x.x.x\x` is the input format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you using marshmallow, you can create own field type

```
    from marshmallow import fields, validate

class IpField(fields.String):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['validate'] = validate.Regexp(r'(^\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}$)',
                                             error='Not valid IP')
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

And if you use `from rest_framework import serializers`

```
serializers.RegexField(regex='(^\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}$)')
```